# altering access callback in hook_menu_alter

Tags: 7, routes

So, I want to set a new function as access callbacks for URLs specified by registration module.

Specifically I want only users that have the update rights on the node to be able to manage registrations for the node.

I implemented hook_menu_alter in this manner:

```
function enge_events_menu_alter($items){
  $items['node/%entity_object/registrations']['access callback'] = 'user_can_manage_registrations';
  $items['node/%entity_object/registrations']['access arguments'] = array(1);
  $items['node/%entity_object/registrations/list']['access callback'] = 'user_can_manage_registrations';
  $items['node/%entity_object/registrations/list']['access arguments'] = array(1);
  $items['node/%entity_object/registrations/settings']['access callback'] = 'user_can_manage_registrations';
  $items['node/%entity_object/registrations/settings']['access arguments'] = array(1);
  $items['node/%entity_object/registrations/broadcast']['access callback'] = 'user_can_manage_registrations';
  $items['node/%entity_object/registrations/broadcast']['access arguments'] = array(1);  
}
```

but for some reason the function never fires.

If I instead redeclare the module's hook_menu and change the access callback functions there, it works and it get's written in the database after a cache clear.

Is it possible to alter access callbacks in hook_menu_alter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function enge_events_menu_alter(&$items){
  $items['node/%entity_object/registrations']['access callback'] = 'user_can_manage_registrations';
  $items['node/%entity_object/registrations']['access arguments'] = array(1);
  $items['node/%entity_object/registrations/list']['access callback'] = 'user_can_manage_registrations';
  $items['node/%entity_object/registrations/list']['access arguments'] = array(1);
  $items['node/%entity_object/registrations/settings']['access callback'] = 'user_can_manage_registrations';
  $items['node/%entity_object/registrations/settings']['access arguments'] = array(1);
  $items['node/%entity_object/registrations/broadcast']['access callback'] = 'user_can_manage_registrations';
  $items['node/%entity_object/registrations/broadcast']['access arguments'] = array(1);  
}
```

$items should be reference variable... For more information [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7)

Comment: checkmark in 5 minutes.